# Best pattern for change notification (events or delegates)

Tags: c#, .net, events, design-patterns, delegates

I have a solution where  i pass a collection of items from a source to a presenter. When the source is updated I want to be able to notify the presenter to show the new result.

What comes to mind is to make a ChangeNotification class, pass it along with the result and have that class notify the presenter. Now as I see it this can be implemented in two ways, either ChangeNotification can have events that the presenter subscribes to, or it can have delegates that the presenter sets and the source calls if it is not null.

The benefits of using events is that more than consumer can react to the notification and you can hook up reactive extensions to it, the downside is that you have to manage subscribe/desubscribtion of the events for proper garbage collection.  Delegates are simple but you lose some flexibility.

What is the most elegant pattern for situation like this? Is there some other way I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will have multiple observers, Events or MultipleDelegates would be required.  If you will only have one observer, and want to enforce that, a delegate would suffice.  However, in terms of which is best, IMHO I would say the event is more flexible and lends itself very well to the pattern.  The ObservableCollection and INotifyPropertyChanged are event based implementations.  By the way, +1 to tbischel for the references to these classes.

Answer (score 2):

There are two built in patterns for this scenerio.

First, you could implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface.  This is better if you want to notify the presenter of changes to properties of the objects themselves in the collection. (or the source object itself, if that is where changes occur).

The second is to pass your presenter an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) containing your objects.   This is better if you want to notify the presenter that an item has been added or removed from the collection.  Both are event driven models that any subscriber could hook into.

---

Edit:  The underlying pattern is the ["Observer"](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternObserver.aspx) pattern... you can roll out your own version if you want, you have the details down.

Comment: To elaborate, if you implement INotifyPropertyChanged then your class will be ready to databind to many WindowsForms or WPF controls when contained in an IBindingList or ObservableCollection. Delegates won't enable this without additional work

Comment: Thanks for your answer, those are collections are useful if you're mainly working with wpf/windows forms. I'm more interested in the underlying pattern in general here though

Comment: they are specific implementations of the "observer" design pattern... and while you get free updates to controls you bind to in Winforms and WPF, they are still extremely useful in non-UI situations.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers that INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged and other related interfaces are property the first place to turn but I wanted to add in third option which would be to implement the observer pattern. If your are not familiar with this pattern, it is how Java achieves it's event functionality through what are called [event listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/intro.html). There is no reason why this pattern cannot be adopted in C# though and in some cases it may provide a more elegant solution than the use of events and delegate especially when there may be several coordinated events that are generally all subscribed to by an interested party.

Another option too is deriving from DependencyObject and implementing DependencyProperties in order to get the change notifications that are built-in and that are optimized for WPF. I tend not to go this route because I don't like the requirement of having a specific base class but there are some good arguments for why it is sometimes the right choice and in fact some MVVM frameworks even use it as the basis of change notifications for ViewModel classes too.